# how to run binary on non-rooted android phone?

Tags: stock-android

I have cross-compiled a binary on Linux using the arm toochain. I uploaded the binary to a non-rooted andnroid phone.

What do I need to do in order to run this binary on the non-rooted phone ?

EDIT: I tried to run via terminal emulator, but I get the following error.

```
$ pwd
/mnt/sdcard/external_sd
$ ls -l hello
-rwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw     8420 2013-12-31 22:12 hello
$ ./hello
./hello: permission denied
$
```

Comment: I suppose you could install a terminal emulator, navigate to the binary, and use `./binary` to invoke it. Making sure permissions are properly set, of course.

Comment: I tried this, but the file is not executable on sdcard, i tried chmod +x, but it does nothing. I tried to copy binary to /data folder on phone, but got permission error. How can i run it ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and give us the output of `ls -l [file]`? You won't be able to move anything to `/data/` because it's owned by `root`.

Comment: check my edit above

Comment: sdcard is probably (usually) FAT32/exFat, so it doesn't have Linux permission system, which is why you can't execute or `chmod` anything on it.  I would try to find a "rw" partition using `mount` (e.g. `/cache`) and trying to execute from there.

Comment: As mentioned above, I tried to copy to /data (mounted rw) but I still get permission denied error, same with /cache.

Comment: Try `sh hello` while in the same directory as your executable. That even works on SDcard.

Comment: sh is for running shell scripts, right ? not for running compiled binaries, right ? Anyway, it gives me ""hello:1:Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting")")"", because it is expecting a shell text script file, not a binary.

Comment: Well, it might be a bit difficult to create a little shell script wrapper :) OK, so a little more detailed: `echo "./hello" > hey && sh hey` will do. IOW: first create a shell script that does nothing but execute the binary, and then let `sh` run that shell script. Sorry, thought that was clear – obviously I was a little cryptic ;)

Comment: It gives me : "hey: ./hello: permission denied".

Comment: @Izzy, Even though `sh` can run the script, doesn't anything it runs in turn still have to have the proper permissions?

Comment: `/data/local` should be writable typically, even though other portions of `/data` are not. Try moving the binary there, marking it executable with `chmod` (if needed), and then running it.

Comment: I tried to copy "cp hello /data/local", it gave me "cp:/data/local/hello: Permission denied".

Comment: @dotVezz Not necessarily. I didn't try it with a binary recently (so you might be right concerning that), but shell scripts do not need to be executable when passed as argument to `sh`. aseaudi: That error is strange. Can you do a `ls -l /data/local` (to see whether the file already exists, but is owned by a different user)?

Comment: @Izzy, "ls -l /data/local" gives me "opendir failed, Permission denied"

Comment: My bad, `/data/local` is owned by `system:system`, and not world-readable. But unless a similar permission issue exists there as well, `ls /data/local/hello` should work. If it does, please also cross-check with `id` to see whether the user matches.

Answer (score 4):

You can download [termux](https://termux.com/), copy your binary to the termux home folder and run it

```
cp /storage/emulated/0/mybinary .
chmod +x mybinary
./mybinary
```

I haven't actually managed to run something because I don't have an android binary handy and a quick google doesn't bring up any android *hello world* binaries, but it should work.

Comment: A *hello world* binary on android isn't any different than on any other system. Try this one, https://github.com/leachim6/hello-world/blob/master/c/c.c

Comment: Tried this with Android Terminal Emulator and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Removable media, as well as several other (user writable) partitions are mounted NOEXEC, meaning you can't execute binaries on these partitiions.
See the output of 'mount' for details.
Modern android builds generally prevent you from copying binaries to partitions mounted EXEC as a security precaution.

Short of rooting your device, you can't run this binary.

Comment: This one's correct.

Comment: is it possible to overcome this? for example by requesting a permission to write in a exec zone?

Comment: You need to pack the binary into an app now, and execute it via the app (possibly with NDK?).  Or if you're lucky, you can copy it to `/data/local/tmp/` then `chmod +x` it, and execute it from there.

Comment: `mount | grep -v noexec` to find which partiotions are not `noexec` so that's possible to run binary files, or maybe better way `mount | grep -v noexec | grep ext4`